# Excel VBA Average of each cell on each worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with multiple worksheets and the worksheets are layed out exactly the same. For example C5 could be cycle time, and I want to know the average cycle time over all the sheets. The only issue is that I have a lot of data, I have data from row 5 through 125004, and columns A through J. I am unsure of how to average the data onto one sheet at the end that still has the 125004 rows and columns A through J, just displaying the average from all the worksheets.

Comment: You're being unclear as to where you're trying to get this average from - is it cell C5 on each sheet, or from this large range on each sheet?

Comment: Cell C5 has the cycle time data on every sheet, I want the average cycle time, therefore the average of C5 over the whole workbook. However, it isn't just C5 that I want to average, its C5 and C6 and C7 so on all the way to C125004, and thats just column C, I want to do it for columns A through J

Answer (score 1):

A [3D formula](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/formulas/three-dimensional.htm) would appear to be adequate, such as:

```
=AVERAGE(Sheet1:Sheet3!C5)
```

copied around to suit.

Comment: That's for sure the best answer when the sheets are really standardized.

Comment: This works really well, however, I have 1,250,000 cells to fill with data, and copying and pasting would take much too long

Answer (score 0):

Create a module in VBA and write the following

```
Public Function GetAllSheetsAverage(makeUpdate As Boolean) As Double
If makeUpdate Then
    Application.Volatile
End If
Dim rng As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set rng = Application.Caller
Dim sum As Double
sum = 0
Dim count As Integer
count = 0
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sht.Name = rng.Worksheet.Name Then GoTo SkipOwnSheet

    Dim rng2 As Range
    Set rng2 = sht.Range(rng.Address)

    sum = sum + rng2.Value

    count = count + 1

SkipOwnSheet:


Next sht

GetAllSheetsAverage = sum / count
```

End Function

The use the function `=GetAllSheetsAverage(TRUE())` on the cells.
The TRUE will make the function listen to every change in the worksheets, so it'll probably be slow on such a huge amount of data.
You can change to false, but the you'll have to update the values manually whenever there is a change on the values from the other sheets.